# Sprite Kit creating a new screen (Restart Method)

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am testing my game over method when u tap the display sides across from the the right side of the screen (self.frame.size.width) to the center(self.frame.size.width/2) then when u tap again it sides back to (self.frame.size.width)(off the screen)

instead of changing all my varibles in my reset method i want to create a new scene of the same scene.

```
        GameScene* NewScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
        NewScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        [self.view presentScene:NewScene];
```

my viewcontroller

```
 scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

It works but (its suppose to be off the screen) and also its size increased.

[image]

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self gameover];
if(direction == 1){
[self reset];
}

[self endInterFace];

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    location = [touch locationInNode:self];
}

[self handleDirectionChange];


}

 -(void)gameover{


    [score_Display runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2+50) duration:0.30]];
    [ScoreFINAL runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2+50) duration:0.30]];
    [highScoreFINAL runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2-35) duration:0.30]];
    [score_Retry runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2-120) duration:0.40]];
    [score_Rate runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2-220) duration:0.55]];
    [score_Share runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2-300) duration:0.75]];


}

-(void)reset{

    [score_Display runAction:[SKAction moveTo:score_DisplayXY duration:0.30]];
    [ScoreFINAL runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/2+50) duration:0.30]];
    [highScoreFINAL runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height/2-35) duration:0.30]];
    [score_Retry runAction:[SKAction moveTo:score_RetryXY duration:0.40]];
    [score_Rate runAction:[SKAction moveTo:score_RateXY duration:0.55]];
    [score_Share runAction:[SKAction moveTo:score_ShareXY duration:0.75]];



GameScene* NewScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
NewScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[self.view presentScene:NewScene];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the issue was that the view might be distorted because of the aspect ratio

solution:

Replace

```
GameScene* NewScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
```

With

```
GameScene* NewScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
```

Comment: Basically restart the scene every time u tap ( for testing only)

Comment: Just a random guess but try self.bounds.size

Comment: You have : self.view.bounds.size, i said try self.bounds.size. I think your view might be distorted because of your aspect ratio

Comment: Also lets see your toucheBegan function, or wherever you implement the tap gestures.

Comment: Did you try self.bounds.size? But yea self.frame.size will work too. The idea at the end is that the view is manipulated. I updated my answer to be more fitting.

Comment: Self.bounds.size throws an error because I think bounds is apart of skveiw

Comment: Ah yea!! I always do let skView = self.view! as SKView and scene.size = skView.bounds.size

Answer (score 0):

self.frame.size instead of self.view.bounds.size